# Internal Errors Galore, Ubuntu not installing

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, partitioning

So I have been trying to install ubuntu onto a new hardrive I got, I managed to do it before with some minor issues. I got a pretty good knowledge of computers and know my ins and outs very well but I have tried very hard to figure this all out on my own but nothing I have tried seems to work. I am install Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (32 bit, due to limit of motherboard) and I have checked its MD5 hash many times. I have used LiLi, Universal Usb installer, and Unetbootin. Nothing has worked. So This time I typed out everything I was doing and what happened each time and during each step so that I could get the most help possible.

```
System Infomation,
Intel Motherboard MQ96510J.86A.1761.2009.0326.0001
Intel Pentium 4 CPU 3.20 GHz (tends to run at 70 C idling dont know if normal)
DDR2 5120 MB total
Intergated Intel Graphics
Nvida Graphics Geforce 7100s Turboforce VGA 
Installing to WD 1 TB hardrive brand new
250 GB and 400 GB hardrives both with Windows Vista have old files want to keep, not being installed to.
Used LiLi to make USB stick.
```

Boot computer, everything starts out fine so go straight to install ubuntu.

Check download updates and install third party

```
COntine... System hangs for about 1 minute. 
"Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of SCS1 (0,0,0) (sda)..."
"Installer Crashed!" When Time window appears
Goes to console "*Starting Mouting network filesystems  [OK]"
"*Stopping Mouting network filesystems  [OK]"
AT which point nothing can be done restart.
```

Reboot everything fine, go to Try Ubuntu.

Goes to desktop.

```
Click "Install Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS"
Nothing, click again.
"System program problem detected" pops up
"Report Problem"
"Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error"
"Show Details"
Executable Path
    /usr/sbin/aptd
    (message box dissappeared before anything else showed up)
"Report Problem"
"Invalid Problem Report... TypeError(Error('Incorrect padding',),)"
ANother Internal Error
Details
/usr/share/ubiquity/...(missed the rest because window disappeared)
Another internal error
contine...
Repeat.
Try to open "Install Ubuntu" Again.
Window to install pops up (Oh god maybe something different!)
English->Contine
Internal Error... (nope)
Buttons disappear and nothing more can be done.
Turn off... Give up...
```

Post Question for help.

Anything you can do to help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for any bad spelling or bad grammar but I just want this thing to work. Thanks

Comment: Did you try installing it with a different live usb? (not necessarily a different usb device) I think the installer might be corrupted ... would you try?

Comment: I have tried LiLi, Universal Usb installer, and Unetbootin. And three different usb devices (a 2 Gb, 4 Gb and 8 Gb).

Comment: oh oh okay sorry :D that **totally** excludes corruption

Comment: I have tried to install a 64 bit system before with this motherboard (before I got a 32 one to work on a different hard drive) and it said something along the lines that the motherboard does not support x64. I could try it again cause I got nothing to lose...

Comment: mmm I don't know. I'm just looking over and over what you've typed. I can't figure out anything. ... last thing I can say maybe it has to do with the connection of the hard disk to the computer in some sort of way. wait for an answer and don't give up :)

Comment: I'm open to trying anything, (even if I have to sacrifice a calculator to the god of computers), I have already tried switching SATA cables, and have checked that the disc works fine. I have already tried everything I could think of which is why I turn to the internet. Anyways Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's the spirit!! hahahahaha

Comment: I had similar issues on an AMD MB from Gigabyte. Turned out to be a bad memory slot. I guess Linux accesses different addresses than Windows 7 that ran fine on this computer. Try checking your memory. I had 4 sticks installed and just removed one at a time until I found the slot in question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work for me! Yay!

Here is what I did, I downloaded a new ISO, check the MD5 again, brand new flash drive and checked the MD5 on that as well. I then did a memory test and found the memory that was possible causing issues. After fixing that I had the install run with `nomraid` and `edd=on`.

After that the install worked fine. Not sure which part was what allowed it to work for me but if you are having the same issue try these.